# No overload for 'method' matches delegates 'System.eventhandler'

Tags: c#, xaml, animation

I'm trying to check when one animation has finished in xaml/c# so I have used the "Completed" event which looks like

```
<Storyboard Completed="firstAnimationCompleted">
```

And I have created the method in my C# for it which looks like...

```
private void firstAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textblock.Text = "Finished";
}
```

so when the animation finishes it should change the specified textblock to "Finished" but for some reason I get the following error...

> No overload for 'method' matches delegates 'System.eventhandler'

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in adance

Comment: Are you sure that the method is in the right file? Is that `EventArgs` definitely the existing `System.EventArgs` class, not some other type you've created?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I'm sure it is

Comment: does your message really state "No overload for 'method'..." or does it state the name of your method?

Comment: (I'm pretty sure it doesn't talk about `System.eventhandler` either, given that the message would use the right case...)

Comment: @RicardoAppleton no it says No overload for 'firstAnimationCompleted'... and JonSkeet yes, yes it does just say System.EventHandler thank you. And it doesn't matter, I've sorted it now anyway.

Comment: Great. Then you might want to share your solution, incase someone else runs into the same problem

Comment: @RicardoAppleton I will shortly, but with under 10 rep I'm not allowed to post a solution to my own question until at least 8 hours have passed since posting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say it in your question, but I think your app is a Windows Store app; in WinRT, the [`Completed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.completed) event is of type `EventHandler<object>`, unlike the [`Completed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) event in WPF, Silverlight and Windows Phone, which is of type `EventHandler`. This is why the second argument must be of type `object`,  rather than `EventArgs`.

You should *always* mention which platform you're working on in your questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

ookay I've fixed it by changing the method in c# to this..

```
private void firstAnimationCompleted(object sender, object e)
{
    textblock.Text = "Finished";
}
```

although I'm not sure why considering the documentation said to put EventArgs e. So any insight to that would be nice!

Comment: Have you tried `System.EventArgs` instead of just `EventArgs`? I suspect you created an `EventArgs` in your project... it can happen if you accidentally use the "create class from usage" feature

Comment: @ThomasLevesque just tried it, and it gave me exactly the same error